# How do I keep my RabbitMQ worker functions active as Lambda functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rabbitmq

These worker functions are RabbitMQ consumers that process incoming requests and reply with responses.

I'm looking for guidance on how to keep these worker functions always active after deploying the Lambda function. What configurations or practices can help achieve this?

```js
// app.js
import e from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import 'dotenv/config.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import SwaggerRouter from './swagger.js';
import logger from './logger.js';
import StartUpRouter from './routes/user_founder.js'
import VCRouter from './routes/user_vc.js';
import SuperAdminRouter from './routes/superadmin.js';
import { handleVCListRequest, startTokenValidationWorker, startUserValidationWorker, startVCDataWorker } from './workers/messageQueueWorker.js';
import { startWorker } from './services/rabbitMQService.js';
import { processMessage } from './workers/emailWorker.js';

const app = e();
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(SwaggerRouter);

// ...other routes and middleware...

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4001);
  logger.info({listening: `Server is Processing on ${process.env.PORT}.`});
  logger.info({success: "Connected to AuthenticationService Database."});
  console.log({listening: `Server is Processing on ${process.env.PORT}.`});
  console.log({success: "Connected to Database."});

  startWorker(processMessage).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error while sending email:', error.message);
  });

  startTokenValidationWorker().catch((error) => {
    logger.error('Error starting token validation worker:', error.message);
    console.error('Error starting token validation worker:', error.message);
  });

  // ...other worker functions...

  handleVCListRequest().catch((error) => {
    logger.error('Error starting vc list worker:', error.message)
    console.error('Error starting vc list worker:', error.message);
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  logger.error({error: err.message});
  console.error({error: err});
});

export default app;

// lambda.js
import ServerlessHttp from "serverless-http";
import app from "./app.js";

export const handler = ServerlessHttp(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single AWS Lambda invocation (instance) cannot run more than 15 minutes. The way you have currently designed your system, simply will not work in an AWS Lambda environment.

If you were running RabbitMQ through Amazon MQ, you could have Amazon [automatically invoke your Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-mq.html) when there are messages in your Amazon MQ RabbitMQ instance. In that setup, your Lambda function would not connect to RabbitMQ, instead it would be invoked with the messages to process inside the `event` object.

If you are not using Amazon MQ to run your RabbitMQ server, then AWS Lambda is just not going to work, and instead you need to use a service like EC2 or ECS that runs your event processing service all the time.

Comment: ok i am using the amazonmq rabbitmq instance. but new with rabbitmq so dont know how to configure it properly so i guess there might be some issues with the rabbitmq worker configurations

Comment: Well you need to follow the instructions in the link I provided. Did you configure AmazonMQ as an event source for Lambda? You have written your Lambda function totally wrong to work with an AmazonMQ event source by the way. It looks like you've just copied standard server-side code for RabbitMQ instead of writing a proper AWS Lambda function.